# ACF relationship fields - get_field values from other post type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my POSTS page (regular post type), I have setup a ACF relationship field. Inside this I can select company name which are all under the post type of directory_listings.

Now, I have the following code on the directory listings page, and therefore using simply get_field does not work because those values are not on this page, they are elsewhere on the POST type instead.

So unsure how to grab the information.

**Code on one of the pages which is under the DIRECTORY_LISTINGS post type:**

```
$posts = get_field('related_articles');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Example diagram as I am not great with explaining via text.
[image]

Currently I have setup the relationship field on the company edit page (directory_listing) instead. It works when doing the following:
1) Related Posts to this business listing -> select a post -> publish - > now displays the list on the business listing page. Example here: http://bit.ly/1vwydDl (bottom of the page)

2) I'd like from the POST edit page select a business which posts will appear on. I can put the field there via ACF no problem but getting it to actually display the results I cannot figure out.

Comment: Each post has got an ID, so when you call `get_field` in your foreach, you need to pass the $post->ID with it. I guess that's what you mean, right?

Comment: Well the get_field is getting nothing right now because the 'related_directories' field is found on the 'post' type not 'directory_listings' post type. So var_dump($posts) shows nothing/NULL at the moment which is expected considering.

It needs to go into a different post type, grab the information and bring it back to the directory_listings post type to output the info.

Comment: Yes, so in the file where you get your posts, you call the relations field. Then you loop through your $posts variable. 
`<?php foreach( $posts as $post): 
       $some_field = get_field('field_name', $post->ID); ?>`
Something like that should work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Background Info:

[get_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) has three parameters:

1. `$field_name`: the name of the field to be retrieved. eg "page_content" (required)
2. `$post_id`: **Specific post ID where your value was entered.** *Defaults to current post ID (not required). This can also be options / taxonomies / users / etc*
3. `$format_value`

If you were only concerned with grabbing a specific post (of which you knew the ID), the key would be the second parameter (`$post_id`). There's nothing really magical about ACF. Quite simply: the `meta_value` (i.e. the directory listing the post is tied to) is saved to each post (attached to that post's `$post_id`).

However, in your case, we don't know the ID of the post(s) we want to get.

### Solution:

If we explain what you want to do in a simple sentence, that sentence would look something like:

> Show/get posts on a `directory_listings` (custom post type) page which have a `meta_value` which points to that page.

Obviously, you can't use `get_field()`, because your problem has nothing to do with "getting a field." Rather, you need to "find the posts that have a specific field." ACF has [great documentation on this](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/).

Luckily for you, WordPress ships with an awesome class called a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and a similarly awesome function called [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). So looking back at our sentence above and translating it into a function, we want to: `get_posts()` where the `meta_key` has a `value` of the current `$post_id`.

Or, more specifically, on your `directory_listings` page, you'd have the following query:

```
$related_articles = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'related_articles', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

if( $related_articles ): 
    foreach( $related_articles as $article ): 

    // Do something to display the articles. Each article is a WP_Post object.
    // Example:

    echo $article->post_title;  // The post title
    echo $article->post_excerpt;  // The excerpt
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $article->ID );  // The thumbnail

    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Good question, great answer.  If only all SO questions and answers were like this.

Comment: I've put this in my page (single.php). Selected a related company from the POSTS page in admin, (Design Locker) and published. Now on that company page the title Design Locker appears. Not the posts title. I've put the_title;

I think maybe because this page is already in a loop. I tried changing things to new WP_Query but then it just came back with the 10 most recent posts, ignored the args.

Comment: You can't use `the_title()` to access the title of the `$related_articles`, unless you `setup_postdata()` (have a look at the codex link I posted for `get_posts()`). Since you're already in the loop, you may be better off using `echo $article->post_title`.

Comment: That's it! Working perfect with that, thank you!

Now that I have to do $article-> first, do the tags change? I tried $article->the_excerpt; but with no result. Same with trying to get the thumbnail.

Comment: If you look at the [return value of get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Return_Value), you'll see it returns a [WP_Post object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) <-- click on that. The excerpt would be accessed via `$article->post_excerpt`. The thumbnail would be `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $article->ID )`. Please close up this question, if my answer solves the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks again, will look into the codex from now. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. The Codex is really helpful, but definitely takes a while to become familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom field you are looking for within that query then you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$posts = get_field('related_articles');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php the_field('your_custom_field',$post); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly this is the same problem than the one I had.
In my case I preferred working with shortcodes.
Using `[acf field="person"]` with the field being a relationshipt only gave me the ID of the person, but I was unable to acces their fields.
On the other hand, using `[acf field="last_name", post_id=[acf field="person"]`, which would be an ideal solution does not work as the wordpress parser does not allow nested shortcodes.

that is why I cam up with this very small php solution:

```
function import_cf_from_cpt( $atts ) {
    // import custom fields from other custom post types that are connected via a relationship to the calling custom post type
    // shortcode: [import <field from calling CPT of type relationship> <field name from field from other CPT>]
    // ex [import person last_name] --> Doe

    $postID = do_shortcode("[acf field={$atts[0]}]");
    // we use the first attribute to get the ID of the object
    $postField = get_field($atts[1], $postID);
    // next, using the ID we look for the field of the second attribute.
return $postField;
}
add_shortcode( 'import', 'import_cf_from_cpt' );
```

Placing this in the functions.php file allows to use the shortcode

`[import person last_name]` for example, or any other combination to import field values from other posts.