# Advanced Custom Fields Relationship - Basic loop + reversed?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to connect **companies** with **products** using Advanced Customs Fields. These are some pages on my website:

```
www.example.com/companies/apple/
www.example.com/companies/microsoft/
www.example.com/products/iphones/
www.example.com/products/ipods/
```

For example I want to connect Apple with their products (iPhones and iPods).

I have added a relationship field in ACF that is called `related_articles` that is only available when the pages parent is the /companies/-page.

So on Apple's company-page - the products iPhones and iPods have been selected in the custom relationship field `related_articles`.

On page.php I added the following:

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('related_articles');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

On the page `www.example.com/companies/apple/`the following is returned:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/products/iphones/">iPhones</a><br>
<a href="http:// www.example.com/products/ipods/">iPods</a><br>
```

Which works exactly as I want.

The problem is that `http://www.example.com/products/iphones/` and `http:// www.example.com/products/ipods/` is empty. Here I want the relationship to be reversed and `<a href="http://www.example.com/companies/apple/">Apple</a><br>` to be displayed. How can I solve this? Is it possible with a code that is compatible in both ways?

I do not wish to make a second "connection", from products to the companies - this needs to be handeled from a single page and not two. Custom post types is also a no go.

**Updated** - New code from the [Querying relationship fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/) documentation:

```
<?php 

$related_articles = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'related_articles', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
?>

<?php if( $related_articles ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $related_articles as $article ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $article->ID ); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title( $article->ID ); ?></a><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This dosen't return anything (blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible - ACF allows for 2 way or reverse querying of related items. So, your product page, you could do the following (with your own relevant acf names)

```
global $post;
$related_company = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'=>'company',
        'meta_query'=>array(
            array(
                'key' => 'related_product',
                'value' => '"'.$post->ID.'"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
));
```

The whole process is explained in detail on the ACF site: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Although, whether this is possible without using Custom Post Types, I'm not certain.

Comment: I updated my question and accordingly to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27446295/2531736 the `'post_type'=>'post'`should work. It's not returning anything though.

Comment: What is the difference between companies and products in your system. Are they categories or custom post types?

Comment: Both are pages. Changed `'post_type' => 'post',` to `'post_type' => 'page',` and used `<?php echo $article->post_title; ?>` instead of `<?php echo get_the_title( $article->ID ); ?>` seems to made it work. It only seems to work on the "product"-pages and not the "company"-pages.

Comment: Nevermind the last part, `<?php echo get_the_title( $article->ID ); ?>` works just as good.