# PHP Counting With Related Articles

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

my goal is to display related articles below a post (check if available, then loop through the ones that are there). It works fine if I have 3 or 6 setup but if I have only 5, it displays automatically the original post as the sixth related article.

```
echo "<div class='related-posts'>";
    $related_articles = get_field('related_articles', false, false);
    $id = $related_articles[0];
    if($id) {
        echo "<h5 class='related-posts_h'>Ähnliche Artikel, die du lesen musst</h5>";

        echo "<ul class='related-posts_list clearfix'>";

                for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) { 

                $id = $related_articles[$i-1];
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail($id) ) {
                        echo "<li class='related-posts_item'>";
                        echo "<figure class='featured-thumbnail thumbnail large'>";
                        echo "<div class='hider-page'></div>";
                            echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)." title='".get_the_title($id)."'>";
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'medium-thumb' );
                            echo "<span class='zoom-icon'></span>";
                            echo "</a>";
                        echo "</figure>";

                    } else { 
                        "<figure class='thumbnail featured-thumbnail'>";
                        echo "<div class='hider-page'></div>";
                            echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."' title='".get_the_title($id)."'>";
                            echo "<img src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/empty_thumb.gif' alt='".get_the_title($id)."' />";
                            echo "</a>";
                        echo "</figure>";
                }
                    echo "<h6><a href='".get_permalink($id)."'>";
                    echo get_the_title($id);
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</h6>";
                echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
echo "</div><!-- .related-posts -->";
```

Comment: Have you seen this [question? (click here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403089/acf-relationship-fields-get-field-values-from-other-post-type)   `if ($post)....` and `foreach($post)...`  I think that would make more sense

Comment: Please provide the output of  $related_articles

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. check after the for loop whether the related Post ID is not equals to the original post ID then only display the related Posts

that is

```
$id = $related_articles[$i-1];
if(get_the_ID() != $id){
   //then do the stuff
}
```

I Hope you are in the details or single.php page so you will get the ID of original post by `get_the_ID()`

```
echo "<div class='related-posts'>";
    $related_articles = get_field('related_articles', false, false);
    $id = $related_articles[0];
    if($id) {
        echo "<h5 class='related-posts_h'>Ähnliche Artikel, die du lesen musst</h5>";
        echo "<ul class='related-posts_list clearfix'>";

        for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
            $id = $related_articles[$i-1];
            if(get_the_ID() != $id){

                if ( has_post_thumbnail($id) ) {
                    echo "<li class='related-posts_item'>";
                    echo "<figure class='featured-thumbnail thumbnail large'>";
                    echo "<div class='hider-page'></div>";
                    echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)." title='".get_the_title($id)."'>";
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'medium-thumb' );
                    echo "<span class='zoom-icon'></span>";
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</figure>";
                } else { 
                    "<figure class='thumbnail featured-thumbnail'>";
                    echo "<div class='hider-page'></div>";
                        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."' title='".get_the_title($id)."'>";
                        echo "<img src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/empty_thumb.gif' alt='".get_the_title($id)."' />";
                        echo "</a>";
                    echo "</figure>";
                }
                echo "<h6><a href='".get_permalink($id)."'>";
                echo get_the_title($id);
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</h6>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
echo "</div><!-- .related-posts -->";
```