# Wordpress ACF display relationship issue

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having trouble finding documentation for displaying the relationship fields between two custom post types.

Essentially I have a stores post type that holds store names and images. Then I have a product post type where each product will have fields where you can select what stores it is available at and a section for a link to the product within that store.

Setup:
I have two custom post types 1: Stores, 2: Products

The fields for "products" are

- [repeater] product_stores

  - [sub field] store_name (RELATIONSHIP)
  - [sub field] store_link (URL)

The fields for "stores" are

- title (WP DEFAULT TITLE)
- image (IMAGE)

I'm able to display the custom field type for the retailer link but having trouble pulling the retailer name and image into the page.

What I have so far

```
              <?php
        if( have_rows('product_stores') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('product_stores') ): the_row(); ?>

                <?php the_sub_field('store_link'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is an old question of mine also relating to the relationship field and post types of any use? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403089/acf-relationship-fields-get-field-values-from-other-post-type

Comment: I actually came across that previously and I keep getting empty values returned when I follow that answer. Thank you though!

Comment: Once I run on a similar problem... and the only way to solve it was to use for loops and arrays... https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update_field-with-nested-groups-and-repater-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a Repeater field with a Relationship field inside it - just use a single Relationship field. The field will return an array of post objects which you can pull the title and link from.

```
<?php 

$stores = get_field('product_stores'); // your Relationship field

if( $stores ) {
    foreach( $stores as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); 
        the_title();
        the_permalink(); // pull whatever you need from the post.
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}

?>
```